# Class Google_client not found on the server, but on localhost it's ok

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, elgg

I'm trying to use the OAuth2 php google library with the elgg engine  and it's working good on localhost, but I have an error `Class 'Google_client' not found...` on the server, the server uses ssl protection, I don't know any other reasons why it's not working.

```
elgg_register_library('AOuth:gmail', $path.'/myModul/vendor/vendor/autoload.php');
elgg_load_library('AOuth:gmail');
$client = new Google_client();
```

Where can be problem?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the server use the same configuration as localhost, specially as far as PHP and Composer versions installed ?

It looks like an autoloader problem (Class not found), I had that on a couple of server where I used Google API. Google API needs PHP >= 5.3, and by default, Composer. But you can use a SPL autoloader for some configurations instead if you don't have Composer.